# Check if first character is the same as the last character?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have an idea with this and that we would have to use `grep` with back references, however this is the closest I could get

```
grep "^[a-zA-z]\$[a-zA-z]\
```

My issue is that I'm not sure as to how to check if the first character == to the last character?

Comment: Different answers are correct depending on if you're doing this for multiple lines (e.g. being read from a stream or file) or a single line (e.g. a string stored in a variable). Which case do you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need

```
grep -E '^([a-zA-Z]).*\1$'
```

capture first character within `(...)` and use its back-reference as last character and skip everything else between `.*`. the `-E` switch enables the *Extended Regular Expression* match so we no need to escape capture group within our `grep` command but; you can also do as following and to portability:

```
grep '^\([a-zA-Z]\).*\1$'
```

if you want to output line with a single character only (however this also known as first and last character is the same), you can define its existence optionally, try:

```
grep -- '^\([a-zA-Z]\)\(.*\1\)\{0,1\}$'
```

`\{0,1\}` matches none-or-one occurrence of *pattern* `.*\1` above.

or to match this on every *single* byte character like above are:

```
grep -- '^\(.\)\(.*\1\)\{0,1\}$'
```

By default `grep` is using `--basic-regexp` (Basic-Regular-Expression, BRE) pattern matching, which the meta-characters like `?`, `+`, `{`, `|`, `(`, and `)` lose their special meaning and match literally and to use them as regex, we need to use escaped types `\?`, `\+`, `\{`, `\|`, `\(`, and `\)` or just switch *PATTERN Matching* to ERE with `-E` (But note that POSIX EREs don't have back-references).

---

**To check if a string were the same characters of length *N***:

```
grep -- '^\([a-zA-Z]\{N-HERE\}\)\(.*\1\)\{0,1\}$'
```

Like for *3* length of characters:

```
grep -- '^\([a-zA-Z]\{3\}\)\(.*\1\)\{0,1\}$'
```

again, as said above, this will return line(s) like only *3* (*N* in general) character length `xxx`, if you don't want these, change to:

```
grep -- '^\([a-zA-Z]\{3\}\).*\1$'
```

Comment: Interesting solution. For the second part, can you explain whats going on in the last parentheses ?

Comment: Note that POSIX EREs don't have back-references. The `grep -E '...\1...'` variants are not portable. POSIX BREs do however. The BRE equivalent of ERE `?` is `\{0,1\}`, not `\?` which is a GNU extension.

Comment: Here strings are not portable either.

Answer (score 3):

If processing lines of text, `awk` is the most obvious:

```
awk 'length>1 && substr($0,1,1)==substr($0,length,1)' file
```

If this is for a shell variable:

```
case $var in ''|?) echo no;; "${var#"${var%?}"}"*) echo yes;; *) echo no;; esac
```

```
[ "${#var}" -gt 1 ] && [ "${var%"${var#?}"}" = "${var#"${var%?}"}" ]
```

Comment: The OP would have to clarify to be sure but IMHO the `length>1 &&` isn't appropriate since a single char input (or an empty string) satisfies the criteria that `first character is the same as the last character`.

Answer (score 1):

Why use an external utility like `grep` or `awk` when the test can easily be performed by the shell?

Assuming that the string contains at least two characters - one could argue that last character equals first character if string contains only one character, but I think that the OP's question is about a string containing two or more characters.

```
#!/bin/bash

# set -x
# set -v

is_match() {
   (( ${#1} < 2 )) && return 1
   [[ "${1:0:1}" != "${1: -1}" ]] && return 1
   return 0
}

check() {
   if is_match "$1"
   then
      echo "\"$1\" is a match"
   else
      echo "\"$1\" is not a match"
   fi
}

check ""
check "a?"
check "a*"
check "a"
check "cdc"
check "abbba"
check "é"
check "étéa"
check "été"
```

Output:

```
"" is not a match
"a?" is not a match
"a*" is not a match
"a" is not a match
"cdc" is a match
"abbba" is a match
"é" is not a match
"étéa" is not a match
"été" is a match
```

Comment: Or just `is_match() [[ ${#1} -ge 2 && ${1::1} = "${1: -1}" ]]`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas.  Sure, that will also work.  I kept the logic separate so I could return another return value - such as 2 - in the future to distinguish between the two "error" conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `cut` command as well

```
#!/bin/bash
# GNU bash, version 4.4.20

str="abbba" 
firstchr=$(echo $str |  cut -c 1)
lastchr=$(echo $str  | rev | cut -c 1)

if [ "$firstchr" == "$lastchr"  ]
then
   echo "Yes, match"
else
   echo "No match"
fi
```

**Output :**

Yes, match

Tested on : https://rextester.com/l/bash_online_compiler

Comment: Try with values like `**`, `-Enen`, `$'a\nb'`, `été`...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas   not getting what actually you are saying

Comment: You have some missing quotes around some parameter expansions so characters like `*`/`?` and $IFS characters will cause problems. `echo` can't be used to output arbitrary data. The GNU implementation of `cut` at least works at byte level, so that won't work on multibyte characters (like UTF-8-encoded é). `cut` and `rev` work on every line of the input, so those approaches don't work for values of `$str` that contain newline.

Answer (score 0):

Split current record on an empty string and then compare the first field with the last

```
$ echo "racecar" \
| gawk -F "" '$1 == $NF'
racecar
```

- Note this artifact only works only with `GNU awk` as pointed to by @Ed Morton.

Comment: Splitting on a null string is undefined behavior per POSIX. Some awks will split the input into chars, some will ignore it, others can do whatever else they like.

Comment: @Ed Morton Thank you for pointing the Posix behavior.